# What is the security concerns of AzureAD?

Tags: active-directory, azure

We have lots of documents about Microsoft on-premise AD security problems and methodologies to find them and test them, but for AzureAD there is not much information about the possible problems and how to test them.

- Can I use BloodHound on AzureAD or is there a hack around it to work with it?
- Does Azure has a tool-as-a-service already that we can use?
- Can you recommend some list to check at least manually?

Thank you

Comment: Azure AD and AD are related only in name. They use different protocols and have entirely different threat models. Bloodhound does not work against Azure AD. Tools and product recommendations are often out of scope of this site, but there are such services out there, built by Microsoft as well as third parties.

Answer (score 3):

Azure AD is SaaS so Microsoft is responsible for scanning and securing the infrastructure.  It’s important to understand the division of responsibility between you and Microsoft. On-premises, you own the whole stack but as you move to the cloud some responsibilities transfer to Microsoft. The following responsibility matrix shows the areas of the stack in a SaaS, PaaS, and IaaS deployment that you are responsible for and Microsoft is responsible for.

[image]

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/security-paas-deployments)

I deal with regulated customers on a daily basis and find it useful for them to review our Customer responsibilities matrix.  This helps them understand what they are still responsible for securing in the cloud and what Microsoft is taking as a cloud provider.  You can find them here:

https://servicetrust.microsoft.com/ViewPage/BlueprintOverview

- Can I use BloodHound on AzureAD or is there a hack around it to work with it?

  - BloodHound is a tool for analyzing the trust relationships in Active Directory (ADDS) environments.  While Azure AD and ADDS have similarities, they are not the same products.
- Does Azure has a tool-as-a-service already that we can use?

  - We have [Azure Security Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/security-center/), [Advanced Threat Analytics](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/enterprise-mobility-security/advanced-threat-analytics) and [Azure Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-integrate-activity-logs-with-log-analytics) and many more services that are all designed to help monitor and protect your cloud environment.
- Can you recommend some list to check at least manually?

  - We have documented [best practices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-identity-management-best-practices)

Comment: Very vague answer that doesn't relates to the core of the question.